# Why is my CSS keyframe fade in animation working?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

[image] [image]

Heres the complete CSS for the animation. I have it on an a tag in my html as a class="fadeInUp animated animatedFadeInUp". Does anyone know why it wouldnt be working? I'm not sure what a -webkit-animation is so I did not add it. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Include your code, including HTML, as text so we can test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give your animation call instructions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Formal_syntax

something like 
animation: fadeInUp 2s linear 1;

Comment: thank you used a combination of this and the other answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not writing a library, you could just write simpler code to achieve the same animation effect:

```css
.myAnimatedFadeInUp {
  animation: fadeInUp 1s both;
  opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes...
```

About the code you've given, it's just working for me. Maybe it's not about the snippet you've given above. I've only added `width`, `height`, and `background` to a `div` to make sure it's visualized and it seems working.

```css
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0,40px,0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeInUp {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
.animatedFadeInUp {
  opacity: 0;
}
.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.myAnimatedFadeInUp {
  animation: fadeInUp 1s both;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fadeInUp animated animatedFadeInUp">
</div>

<div class="myAnimatedFadeInUp">
</div>
```

Comment: thank u! got it working by toying with the code

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway next time you should post your code on the question instead of giving images of code to prevent yourself from downvotes of people.

Comment: Btw please make this as the accepted answer because it produces runnable code and a more detailed informative answer than the current accepted one.